# Uncaught ReferenceError: OAuth is not defined

Tags: javascript

[I'm follow this tutorial here so that I can use a Javascript SDK for OAuth.](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-js)

I have downloaded the zip file, extracted the oauth.js file and put it inside my project, linked the script, and then did the initialization with a public key.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <h1>yay!</h1>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="requests.css">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uF4hsoakrUA/sddefault.jpg" id="hello">

    <script src="/path/to/oauth.js"></script>
    <script>
       OAuth.initialize('Khtcm8GGKuezCJE1qU6ED7y9p');
    </script>

</head>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the contents of the script tags source file?

Comment: Do you literally have `/path/to` in your file? You're supposed to replace it with the actual path.

Comment: @Juhana Oh whoops! My bad, thank you.